# Laravel SVG file validation isn't accepting svg files

Tags: laravel, svg, laravel-validation

I'm trying to accept SVG files as icons but the validation always fails for some reason.

I tried removing "image" rule in the controller. and added the mimes only but that didn't work.

```
            'icon'            => 'required|mimes:png,jpg,jpeg,svg,html|max:2000',
```

Why does it always fail? Is there something wrong with the rule I've made??

Comment: Are you sure the file has svg mimetype? There's a difference between the file extension and the file mimetype, maybe you're confusing them?

Comment: According to the documentation the file you want to validate should be of the mimetype `image/svg+xml` when using the `mimes:svg` rule

Comment: Also you could check what the exact error of the validator is like so `$errors = $validator->errors();`

Comment: for some reason it doesn't accept all svg's. Only some svg files work. Not sure why.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem, but was able to solve it with **mimetypes** instead of using **mimes**. I also noticed that sometimes SVGs were entering as `text/plain` and other times as the usual `image/svg+xml`.

So, in this case, I would use both within the validator. Like this:

```
'icon' => 'required|mimetypes:text/plain,image/png,image/jpeg,image/svg',
```

Hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and found that my .svg file doesn't have xml tag like:

`<?xml version="1.0"?>`

Laravel 5.8